# Integration test not working with Spring Boot and Test Containers

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, integration-testing

I implemented a project with Spring Boot + MySQL + Docker + Fly way. I created a test class for the integration testing using test containers. Below mentioned the implemented test class.

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class UserControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserController userController;

    @Autowired
    UriComponentsBuilder builder;

    @Container
    public static MySQLContainer container = new MySQLContainer("mysql:latest")
            .withDatabaseName("example_db")
            .withUsername("Test")
            .withPassword("Test");

    @Container
    public static GenericContainer<?> redis =
            new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("redis:6.2-alpine")).withExposedPorts(6379);

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp(){
        container.withReuse(true);
        container.withInitScript("src/main/test/resources/schema.sql");
        container.start();
        redis.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    public static void overrideProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry){
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", container::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", container::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", container::getPassword);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.driver-class-name", container::getDriverClassName);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser(){
        CreateUserRequestDto request = new CreateUserRequestDto();
        request.setName("Test User");
        request.setAge(45);
        UserResponseDto response = userController.create(request);
        assertNotNull(response);
    }

}
```

When I build the project, every time it search the host db(app_db) which is created in docker container.
Below mentioned the application.yml and docker-compose.yml files I used.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
 version: "3.0"
 services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
    links:
      - mysql_db:app_db
  mysql_db:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

**application.yml**

```
app:
  name: test-service

server:
  port: 8090

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://app_db:3306/test_db
    username: user
    password: password
    initialization-mode: always
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (app_db)

Any help or workarounds are appreciated for solve this issue.

Comment: Without digging into your issue, may I suggest you simply use [JDBC integration](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/) instead? Simpler setup with less headache

Comment: Thanks  @crizzis. Any idea for solve this issue?